# How to determine whether a specific DOM element is visible or not?

Tags: jquery, dom, visibility

Using jQuery, what is the easiest way to determine whether a particular element is visible? I don’t mean visible within the current viewport, but on the page.

Ideally, the function should return `false` if the element or any of its ancestors has a CSS rule such as `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. No need to worry about `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Kidding right? have you just tried to google/or/SOverflow-search "jquery-element-is-visible-or-not?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `:visible` selector with `is` method.

```
if($('elementSelector').is(':visible')){
   //Element is visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is()` method.

```
$('#element').is(':visible');
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('div:visible');` will return all visible `divs`.

Also, it's worth noting this section of the [jQuery 1.3.2 changelog](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3.2#%3avisible.2F%3ahidden_Overhauled):

> In jQuery 1.3.2 an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0. It means that if your element's CSS display is "none", or any of its parent/ancestor element's display is "none", or if the element's width is 0 and the element's height is 0 then an element will be reported as hidden.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```
$('#mydiv').is(":visible");
```